# In Eclipse,defining a data type using another data type,only the latter one test client main() run,how to run only the 1st?

Tags: java, eclipse

This is a question related to an assignment so I'd better not post any code,but my question is specific.

I am new to Eclipse so I just wanna know if what I saw is normal or not and if there is a way out.

What I did is defining a data type,which is a class include Constructor, methods, test client(`static void main()`).I used another data type from another class in an external library.The name of the existed data type is WeightedQuickUnionUF, Let's call it WQUF for short.

I instantiated a variable of type WQUF to use methods that WQUF has.I wrote a test client(`static void main()`) in the buttom of my class to check if my methods work fine.I used a constant like 10 as argument to initialize my data type variable.Then I used my methods on that variable.I used some println statements to output the status of the variable to see if my methods work.

When I clicked Run to run my class, the console showed that class WQUF was running and waiting for input.I opened the WQUF.class.Yes, there is a test client `void main()` inside.

My intention is only to use the methods and private variables in WQUF,of course I couldn't see the private variables.I don't wanna run the WQUF test client which requires input.

My question is, is the situation I'm facing normal?Is there any way to avoid running WQUF test client?

PS:Findbugs found 2 bugs.Said

> dead store to my WeightedQuickUnionUF instance variable and the value
>   of the variable is not used

.Another is that

> the WeightedQuickUnionUF is an unwritten field

.No idea what does that mean.Related or false alarm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is not Eclipse related, but more like you're new to Java and haven't quite figured out how it works.

The main entry point of executing a Java programme, is a "public static void(String[] arguments)". This is where you instantiate your first object (and maybe call some of its methods). So when you right click your class in Eclipse, and choose "Run as java app" it will automatically look for such a main method and invoke it. So what happens when you run it, is really up to the code to what you wrote in that main method...

Perhaps you should post your 2 classes as well to make it simpler for us to understand your problem and guide you into the right direction.

As a side note:

- "dead store" means you're assigning a value to a field/variable without using it later
- "unwritten field" means that you are not assigning it a value (from definition, constructor, method, etc) before you try to use it, so it's always null

Also when you feel comfortable enough with Java, you can take a look at the JUnit or TestNG libraries, which are designed to help you test your code in a standardised way, and not by using main methods.

Cheers

Comment: Yes，man, your answer is the half solution of my problem.I figured the whole myself after tackling sth else and went back to where I dropped this. I did miss the `String[] args` which Eclipse didn't remind me.But before that you have to go into **Run Configurations** to build a configuration manually. In the **Main Class** type down my class name.Then I got what I want.So, it is Eclipse related more or less.Thank you very much.You answer is likely to be my choice.

Answer (score 0):

My question is, is the situation I'm facing normal?
It's absolutely normal, that's what we call encapsulation.

Is there any way to avoid running WQUF test client?
You want to make your own test client method? try extends from `WQUF` class, so it will be `MyWQUF` class then override `testClient()` method.

Comment: both 2 class, mine and WQUF, use a public static void main(), as a test client.Is it clear now?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you said so I edited my post to make it clearer.